# Job Shop Scheduling with Machine Constraint

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am working on a jop shop scheduling problem and trying to integrate a constraint that only allows certain jobs to be assigned to certain machines.
I thought I could do this by creating an additional Set of different types of machines (A,B) and then creating a constraint that only allows jobs with this specific type to be handled on the machine.

**Data:**

```
dict_jobs = {
10 : {'dur' : 45, 'type' : 'A', 'JobDeadline' : '31/05/2022'},
20 : {'dur' : 45, 'type' : 'A', 'JobDeadline' : '31/05/2022'},    
30 : {'dur' : 70, 'type' : 'A', 'JobDeadline' : '27/05/2022'},
100 : {'dur' : 55, 'type' : 'B', 'JobDeadline' : '25/05/2022'},
110 : {'dur' : 75, 'type' : 'B', 'JobDeadline' : '30/05/2022'},
120 : {'dur' : 45, 'type' : 'B', 'JobDeadline' : '30/05/2022'}}


dict_machine = {
111 : {'duration' : 500, 'end' : '16:00:00', 'start' : '08:30:00', 'type' : 'A', 'date' : '30/05/2022'},
222 : {'duration' : 800, 'end' : '17:00:00', 'start' : '08:00:00', 'type' : 'A', 'date' : '25/05/2022'},
333 : {'duration' : 800, 'end' : '17:00:00', 'start' : '08:00:00', 'type' : 'B', 'date' : '30/05/2022'},
444 : {'duration' : 800, 'end' : '17:00:00', 'start' : '08:00:00', 'type' : 'B', 'date' : '25/05/2022'}}
```

**Model**

```
model = ConcreteModel()

model.JOBS= Set(initialize = dict_jobs.keys(), dimen=1)

model.MACHINES = Set(initialize = dict_machines.keys(), dimen=1)

model.TYPES = Set(initialize = ['A', 'B'])

model.TASKS = Set(initialize = model.JOBS * model.MACHINES, dimen=2)


model.MACHINE_ASSIGNED = Var(model.TASKS, domain = Binary)


model.TYPE_JOBS = Set(initialize = [(10 , 'A'), (20 , 'A'), (30, 'A'), (100, 'B'), (110, 'B'), (120, 'B')], dimen = 2)

model.JOB_TYPE = Var(model.TPYE_JOBS, domain = Binary)

model.TYPE_MACHINE= Set(initialize = [(111, 'A'), (222, 'A'), (333, 'B'), (444, 'B')], dimen = 2)

 model.MACHINE_TYPE= Var(model.TYPE_MACHINE, domain = Binary)
```

**Constraint**

```
def type_condition(model, type, machine):
      return (model.MACHINE_ASSIGNED[job, machine] * model.JOB_TYPE[job, type] <=(model.MACHINE_TYPE[machine, type]) for type in model.TYPES)

 model.APPLY_SPEC = Constraint(model.TASKS, rule=type_condition)
```

**Objective**

```
def objective_function(model):
    return summation(model.UTILIZATION)
model.OBJECTIVE = Objective(rule = objective_function, sense = maximize)
```

**Problem**
When I am trying to solve this I am getting this error: "KeyError: "Index '(10, 'B')' is not valid for indexed component 'JOB_TYPE'"".

Any ideas how I can modify the constraint?

Comment: How are the ‘A’ type jobs related to ‘B’ types?  It isn’t clear why you couldn’t solve this as 2 independent problems, which would be simpler…

Comment: In the future I am planning to integrate a third type of job that can be solved on both machines while still having jobs that have to been solved at one specific machine. So it would be good to have such a constraint.

E.g.: 10 : {'dur' : 45, 'type' : 'A', 'JobDeadline' : '31/05/2022'},
20 : {'dur' : 45, 'type' : 'A or B', 'JobDeadline' : '31/05/2022'}}

Answer (score 0):

A couple things will help...

First, you can use a sparse set for the J-M pairings that is restricted to only compatible ones.  This will prevent "illegal" assignments and reduce the size of your model. (see code)

Second, you will likely have need for several types of subsets based on machine type/whatever.  You can & should make those with set comprehensions, etc. and just put those into the model as needed.

Lastly, you might find use for indexed sets, such as a set that is indexed by machine that contains a set of compatible jobs.  The sets of jobs are *indexed* by the set of machines.  (see code)

```
# job-shop setup

import pyomo.environ as pyo

jobs = {
    10: {"dur": 45, "type": ["A",], "JobDeadline": "31/05/2022"},
    20: {"dur": 45, "type": ["B",], "JobDeadline": "31/05/2022"},
    30: {"dur": 70, "type": ["A", "B"], "JobDeadline": "27/05/2022"},
}


machines = {
    111: {
        "duration": 500,
        "end": "16:00:00",
        "start": "08:30:00",
        "type": "A",
        "date": "30/05/2022",
    },
    222: {
        "duration": 800,
        "end": "17:00:00",
        "start": "08:00:00",
        "type": "A",
        "date": "25/05/2022",
    },
    333: {
        "duration": 800,
        "end": "17:00:00",
        "start": "08:00:00",
        "type": "B",
        "date": "30/05/2022",
    }
}

compatible_assignments = {(j, m) for j in jobs.keys() 
                            for m in machines.keys() 
                            if machines[m]['type'] in jobs[j]['type']}
jobs_by_machine = {m: 
    [j for j in jobs.keys() if machines[m]['type'] in jobs[j]['type']]
    for m in machines.keys()}

print(compatible_assignments)
print(jobs_by_machine)

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#SETS
model.J = pyo.Set(initialize=jobs.keys())
model.M = pyo.Set(initialize=machines.keys())
model.JM = pyo.Set(within=model.J*model.M, initialize=compatible_assignments)
model.J_by_M = pyo.Set(model.M, within=model.J, initialize=jobs_by_machine)

model.pprint()
```